# Unable to find dependency 'System.XML' of assembly 'System.Xml.Linq.dll' Version='5.0.5.0'

Tags: .net, xml, linq

I converted my project to VS2010, and my build is failing every time.
The last error that I am having is a warning. 
(Sadly enough I can't show pictures since my reputation isn't 10 yet, so the warning is the following:)

> Warning   1   Unable to find dependency 'SYSTEM.XML' (Signature='7CEC85D7BEA7798E' Version='5.0.5.0') of assembly 'System.Xml.Linq.dll'   C:\Projecten\TMFI\Brady Dolphin Communicator\Brady Dolphin Communicator Setup\Brady Dolphin Communicator Setup.vdproj   Brady Dolphin Communicator Setup

I can go into the setup and find this System.Xml.Linq.dll and if I go into the dependency I find that it is version 5.0.5.0, but that there is an error message there as well.

I can't delete this file, only exclude it, but that didn't fix the problem.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Thanks,

Gert

Comment: Make sure that you have installed Portable Class Library support for VS2010.

Comment: Those are Silverlight version numbers, very hard to guess what you are doing.

Comment: In the end I just deleted the entire setup, and reattached it, and it worked. Very strange that I get such errors, and that it is solved by simply deleting, and readding them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I just deleted the entire setup, and reattached it, and it worked. Very strange that I get such errors, and that it is solved by simply deleting, and re-adding them.